# rewriting Tree like function without recursive

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
class block(object):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N; self.l, self.r, self.u, self.d = [None]*4
    def move_lower(self):
        res = []
        for x in (self.u, self.d, self.l, self.r):
            if x != None and x.N < self.N:
                res.append(x)
        return res
    def move_lower_chain(self, res = [], history = []):
        temp = self.move_lower()
        if len(temp) == 0:
            res.append(history + [self.N])
        else:
            for x in temp:
                x.move_lower_chain(res, history + [x.N])
        return res
```

I tried to change the 'move_lower_chain' function to Non-recursive function, but i couldn't and even didn't know how to solve. most difficult part was below:

```
        for x in temp:
                x.move_lower_chain(res, history + [x.N])
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: `move_lower_chain` is your original recursive function and `move_lower` is your current attempt at making a non-recursive version, correct?

Comment: You can't. You can change the code to not use the system stack but then you'll replaced it with a user stack leaving it a recursive process.

Comment: @Sylwester that is true, but i have the impression that OP is a student.  And this is a classic computer science exercise: *rewrite the recursion as a loop*.  It will still have a stack (as a list) and for the purpose of memory usage it will be the same.  But it is an exercise in learning alright.

Comment: @grochmal yes. another block object will be placed in self.l to self.d.